# make numpy array from text file

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, text

I have text file like this pattern (2 first rows have 5 columns, then third has 3, then again 2rows 5columns, 1 rows 3 colums)

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
6, 7, 8, 9, 10
11, 12, 13
14, 15, 16, 17, 18
19, 20, 21, 22, 23
24, 25, 26
```

I am a very newbie to python and numpy, I would like to have output file like this

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26
```

It mean that I need 2 rows and 13 colums text file from the input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is irregular, so reading it is quite tough: Here is one approach

```
import numpy as np
dat = ','.join(np.loadtxt('file.txt',str, delimiter='\n')).split(',')
np.array(dat, float).reshape(2, -1)
 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13.],
       [14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26.]])
```

Comment: Thanks to onyambu, you give me verry quick and good solution. Thank again bro